# Change the source of a branch in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

Firstly I will provide the structure of my branches

- Trunk

  - Version1 (branch from trunk)

    - CustomerA (branch from Version1)
    - CustomerB (branch from Version2)
  - Version2 (new branch at a later moment in time of trunk)

    - CustomerC (branch from Version2)

Now I want to migrate CustomerB to version2 but I need to keep the changes allready made to the CustomerB branch.

Is this possible and how would I do that? I am using SVN with the TortoiseSVN client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. First, you should make sure both branches are in sync with trunk to minimize conflicts. Then, merge Version2 branch with CustomerB.

For more info check out the book's chapter on [Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html).

Once you learn to use branching and merging fluidly, it becomes a very powerful tool.

Comment: I already knew the chapter about Branching and Merging but I use an incorrect option in the merge window but now it works. thanks